# Reportviewer working in localsystem(remote database) but error in webserver

Tags: reportviewer

reportviwer working fine in localsystem 
when i set reporturl path and remoteserverurl details 
serverurl : http://sriventech.in/ReportServer
reportpath : /invoice.rdlc
and upload the website
it is displaying errror ::
The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

is there any problem with webserver or my reportpath and serverrul details

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are in Local Mode, you have to provide credentials to the reporting server to run reports. The generic 404 is probably masking an authentication error. Make sure you are in the correct Active Directory group if you are using integrated authentication. Otherwise the page should prompt you to log in.